# Multiplying a Vector2 by a Scalar (LibGDX)

Tags: java, android, types, casting, libgdx

I am attempting to multiply the type "Vector2" by a scalar of value delta and type float.  Information on the type Vector2 can be found here:

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/class-use/Vector2.html

Specifically on that page, I am referencing:

Vector2 --- Vector2.scl(float scalar)
Multiplies this vector by a scalar

position is a Vector2
velocity is a Vector2

I am being given the error: "The method scl(float) is undefined for the type Vector2"

```
public void update(float delta) {
    position.add(velocity.cpy()).scl(delta); 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Vector2.scl` method is new.  You must be using an older version of Libgdx.  The method is called `mul` in older versions (this method still exists in the newer Libgdx, but is `@deprecated`):

See http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#mul(float)

Comment: It seems you're right.  As I downloaded libgdx yesterday, and I thought from an updates source, I was attempting to use scl.  Switching to mul fixed things for me.  Thanks for the help!

(Now to update my libgdx...)